# How to get a custom image content type to show up in the Ephox editor?

Tags: content-management-system

Using Percussion CM System, I have a custom content type for images, actually using the PSOImageEditor imedImage type.  How do I get Images of that type to show up in the Content Browser selection list when users click the insert CMS Image icon in Edit Live?  I've scanned through the docs and config files but nothing is jumping out at me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to edit the sys_inline_image slot in workbench under Assembly Design and add the content type/template pair you want to add.

Most slots you are adding a snippet template as the allowed template but for sys_inline_link and sys_inline_variant you add the binary template(s),  this is because the system just generates the link to the item based on its published location scheme for these slots.

You can add more than one template for the same type if you have more than one image field on the type you may have a binary template for each.